# Добавить dll на несколько секунд

Tags: c#, asp.net, framework

Я прекрасно знаю что есть:
`Process.Start();`
`DllImport()`
И так далее.

Но мне нужно чтобы `.dll` файл подключился как управляемый файл, и потом его отключить:
`Timer.Stop();`
`Disponse();`

Есть папка `Services`, и в ней файлы `.dll`(их может быть неографиченное количество), получаю список с помошью `System.IO.Dictonary.GetAllFile();` получаю в итоге массив(`string[]`), и мне нужно чтобы файлы из данной папки я брал по очереди и запускал их.

Запускал `1` файл на `5` секунд, и как только завершился `.dll` (текуший), сразу же запускаю следуюший.

`.dll` файл может как сам завершиться, так и экстренно завершиться по истечению времени.

Использую:
`Visual Studio 2019`
`C# asp.net framework 4.8`(`framework` самой последней версии)

Comment: Используйте соответствующие WINAPI: LoadLibrary. FreeLibrary

Comment: На сколько я знаю загруженную сборку уже нельзя выгрузить из приложения, но есть вариант использовать домены. Можно создать новый домен, загрузить в него сборку и когда будет необходимо, удалить сам домен и его зависимости. [тут](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/appdomain-concept-in-Asp-Net/) кое-что описано на эту тему

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability вот здесь неплохие примеры на эту тему

Comment: У меня это все происходить должно на стороне сервера, эту операцию я запускаю как IHostedServices, .dll файл комрилируется при обращение к api(ControllerBase). Компилирую через класс CSharpCodeProvider();