# Загрузка и выгрузка dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом вы бы загрузили .dll файл, а далее выгрузили файл?

> ### 1 вариант:
>
> ```cs
> var process = Process.Start(@"D:\\source\\repos\\CreateDll\\bin\\Debug\\CreateDll.dll");
> Thread.Sleep(5000);
> process.Kill();
> ```
>
> Проблема в том что dll написана на c#, а по этому просто запустить dll не достаточно, нужно еще вызвать функцию!

> ### 2 вариант:
>
> ```cs
> var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\\source\\repos\\CreateDll\\bin\\Debug\\CreateDll.dll");
>     
> foreach (Type type in dll.GetExportedTypes())
> {
>     dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
>     type.InvokeMember("Main", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, c, null);
> }
> ```
>
> Данный вариант не подходит, так как нельзя остановить работу функции прям во время ее работы.

> ### 3 вариант:
>
> Использование класса AssemblyLoadContext, но о нем я мало что знаю и использовать не умею

> ### 4 вариант:
>
> ```cs
> AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain name");
> // TODO: configure appdomain as needed
> // to load the dll and get a type you can reference in your current appdomain
> string pathToDll = @"C:\somedir\Mydll.dll";
> Type myType = typeof(SomeType);
> SomeType myObj = (SomeType)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, > myType.FullName);
> // to just load the dll into the new appdomain
> byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToDll);
> domain.Load(file);
> ```
>
> О нем тоже к сожалению мало что знаю, и по этому тоже аналогично использовать не умею

> ### ссылки на мои вопросы по этой теме:
>
> [Как через GetProcAddress вызвать функцию из dll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245288/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-getprocaddress-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dll)
>
> [Как написать такую библиотеку чтобы можно было запустить файл на определенное время [дубликат]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236930/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80)
>
> [Запуск .dll файла на определенное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236915/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-dll-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)
>
> [Добавить dll на несколько секунд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215667/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dll-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4)

Comment: 1. Уточните, какую платформу вы используете: .NET или .NET Core - это важно! 2. Эта dll что из себя представляет: программу или библиотеку? Программу можно запустить саму по себе, а библиотеку только использовать в других программах. Это тоже важно!

Comment: Я глянул ваши предыдущие темы. Вы там толком не отвечали на уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. И как вам помочь после этого?

Comment: 3. Эта dll - управляемый (C#/.NET) или неуправляемый (нативный, C/C++) код? Исходники есть или она чужая?

Comment: Ошибка: Вам путь надо писать либо так `"D:\\source\\repos\\CreateDll\\bin\\Debug\\CreateDll.dll"` либо так `@"D:\source\repos\CreateDll\bin\Debug\CreateDll.dll"`. Сейчас пути, показанные в вопросе, написаны с ошибкой.

Comment: здравствуйте, как можно вам написать в личные сообщения?

Comment: vs не ругается, да и компилятор c# нормально воспринимает \\ с @

Comment: собственно создаю я конструктор ботов вк(на группы и пользователи), как вы уже поняли выбрал я c# asp.net, я знаю php гораздо лучше, но в php понятия async вообще не существует, собственно по этому я и выбрал c#. собственно будет сайт(razor pages), api(controller, для приложения, тоже несколько вопросов есть по этому поводу), и собственно фоновый процесс(фоновый процесс будет запускать файлы .dll по очередям, сами файлы .dll создает класс CSharpCodeProvider, логику задают пользователи. собственно пользователь например тыкнул на кнопку добавить условие(запрос к api), и далее я уже на сервере

Comment: принимаю что он хочет, добавляю в код, компилирую, и получается 2 файла, reactions.cs и reactions.dll. собственно так как пользователей будет много, то я и выбрал запуск очередями, то есть например по 1000 пользователей(проц должен выдержать)

Comment: если возникнут вопросы еще говорите, а вообще можно как либо тут на stackowerflow создать диалог или еще что либо?

Comment: `компилятор c# нормально воспринимает \\ с @` это не значит, что здесь нет ошибки.

Comment: Конструктор ботов, а все эти боты с адреса сервера будут в ВК залезать? Первый же бан по IP со стороны ВК прикроет эту затею. Если со стороны юзера, то зачем вам запускать на стороне сервера код? Если со стороны браузера, то вам нужно яваскрипты пилить и запускать их на фронте, а не C# код. В общем, подумайте еще. То есть клепать C# модули и грузить их таким образом - это не только неоптимально, но и бесполезно в итоге, как по мне.

Comment: Нет, смотрите есть например robochat.io, тоже конструктор, его ip один и тот же, и callback у него один, вк его ip не банит, мой не должен следовательно тоже

Comment: _можно как либо тут на stackowerflow создать диалог_ - нет, это не форум, а сайт типа "Вопрос-ответ". Он не предназначен для общения. Задаёте конкретный вопрос - получаете точный ответ. PS: хотя можно общаться в чате, но вряд ли вы кого туда заманите.

Comment: _сами файлы .dll создает класс CSharpCodeProvider_ - отлично, с этим разобрались. Код управляемый, для работы с ним не нужно привлекать PInvoke (а в прошлых вопросах вы зачем-то использовали [DllImport]).

Comment: Вы так и не написали, что именно используете: .NET или .NET Core. Берём современный - Core. Таким образом круг  ̶п̶о̶д̶о̶з̶р̶е̶в̶а̶е̶м̶ы̶х̶  технологий сужается.

Comment: Теперь осталось выяснить, все ли действия в коде dll подпадают под один шаблон. _логику задают пользователи_ - похоже, что нет, в один интерфейс не уместить. Значит, остаётся `AssemblyLoadContext`. Открывайте документацию по нему, осваивайте. Сюда возвращайтесь с _конкретными_ вопросами.

Comment: Вот скажите, хоть что-то в вашем вопросе относится к веб? Зачем вы влепили метку asp.net? Вот заглянет в тему человек, подписанный на эту метку, а тут ни слова про контроллеры, mvc, web api и пр.

Comment: в один интерфейс уместить